# $expand not working. Associate/Child records not returned in result. [UPDATE]

Tags: c#, .net, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, edmx

Hope you all doing great.

Well, I created webApi using c#.
Below is the code which generates result from "../../$metadata" (on bottom of the image)

[image]

Currently, i have hard coded the result, so it should always send the Customer and its associated product, below is the code:

```
        public EdmEntityObjectCollection Get()
    {
        IEdmEntityType customerType = (IEdmEntityType)ODataUntypedSample.Model.FindType("NS.Customer");
        IEdmCollectionType collectionType = Request.ODataProperties().Path.EdmType as IEdmCollectionType;
        EdmEntityObjectCollection collection = new EdmEntityObjectCollection(new EdmCollectionTypeReference(collectionType));

        EdmEntityObject customer1 = new EdmEntityObject(customerType);
        customer1.TrySetPropertyValue("CustomerId", CUSTOMER1id);
        customer1.TrySetPropertyValue("FullName", "Jony Mark One");
        collection.Add(customer1);

        EdmEntityObject customer2 = new EdmEntityObject(customerType);
        customer2.TrySetPropertyValue("CustomerId", CUSTOMER2id);
        customer2.TrySetPropertyValue("FullName", "Pole Sam two");
        customer2.TrySetPropertyValue("Products", GetChildProduct());
        collection.Add(customer2);

        return collection;
    }

    private static EdmEntityObjectCollection GetChildProduct()
    {
        IEdmEntityType productType = (IEdmEntityType)ODataUntypedSample.Model.FindType("NS.Product");

        IEdmCollectionTypeReference entityCollectionType
                        = new EdmCollectionTypeReference(new EdmCollectionType(new EdmEntityTypeReference(productType, isNullable: false)));
        EdmEntityObjectCollection ec = new EdmEntityObjectCollection(entityCollectionType);

        EdmEntityObject product1 = new EdmEntityObject(productType);
        product1.TrySetPropertyValue("ProductId", 99);
        product1.TrySetPropertyValue("CustomerIdRef", CUSTOMER2id);
        ec.Add(product1);

        EdmEntityObject product2 = new EdmEntityObject(productType);
        product2.TrySetPropertyValue("ProductId", 88);
        product2.TrySetPropertyValue("CustomerIdRef", CUSTOMER2id);
        ec.Add(product2);

        return ec;
    }
```

When I browse the url using with "$expand" it only returns the Customer data, it doesnt returns child/associate product data. Could anyone please explain, why it is behaving like this?

query: http://localhost:12345/odata/Customers?$expand=Products
Result:

```
[{"CustomerId":11,"FullName":"Jony Mark One"}, 
 {"CustomerId":22,"FullName":"Pole Sam two"}]
```

Comment: did you 'EnableQuery'?

Comment: On adding the "[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]" - it throws an error " Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)."

Comment: Any suggestion, that why it is not working? Or any sample to set the child record? [Github source code](https://github.com/piyushparate1/SampleODataUntyped)